# I cannot see pages & other resources on the admin central

Tags: maven, magnolia

I have a magnolia project that i pulled from a repository. I have imported this into intellij IDEA ultimate edition successfully. I am deploying this on a tomcat server. On the deployment tab, I have selected **webapp:war exploded** as the artifact to be deployed. It deploys successfully and launches the magnolia admin central.

However, I cannot see the pages under the pages app. Also I do not have an option to preview the website as a visitor. I have solved several bugs and now I am facing this error: **Duplicated keys found while loading message bundles from ./mgnl-i18n**

What does this mean? Pls help

Answer (score 0):

The error message is just a warning and not a big deal, in fact it's normal. If you want demo content we have demo-projects, I assume you have the Community edition version then please add the following dependencies to your webapp with version of your choice.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>info.magnolia.demo</groupId>
  <artifactId>magnolia-travel-demo</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>info.magnolia.demo</groupId>
  <artifactId>magnolia-travel-tours</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

For more information:
https://git.magnolia-cms.com/projects/MODULES/repos/demo-projects/browse/community
and 
https://wiki.magnolia-cms.com/display/WIKI/Setting+up+a+Magnolia+website+project

Hope this helps,

Cheers,

Comment: Hi, two clarifications:
1. How do I add the preview option on the magnolia admin central?
2. To which POM do I add the two dependencies?

Comment: I have added the dependencies on the parent POM file, they have imported successfully but the pages app is still empty.

Comment: I have added the dependencies on the webapp POM file, they have imported successfully but the pages app is still empty.

Comment: travel-demo automatically imports some content, if it was successful. perhaps it better to import this https://git.magnolia-cms.com/projects/PLATFORM/repos/ce-packs/browse/magnolia-community-demo-webapp and deploy it, that brings the said modules and bootstraps necessary content.